# To add sets into a data structures in C++ preferably

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to add sets {1,3,5} and set {2,8} into a "list". How or which data structure should I use?

I basically want it to be able to store groups. I tried vector of vectors, or I need set with multiple key values in C++.

```
sets = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}};
```

Comment: Vector of vectors could be good. What did you dislike about this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The standard library has a set data structure already.

A vector of sets would be the simplest approach:

```
std::vector<std::set<int> >
```

Comment: vector of sets would store 1,2 ,3 in one set and this is at one l;ocation element of vector s it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. A vector of set would store three sets: the first containing `{1,2,3}`, the second containing `{2,3}` and the third containing `{3,5}`. Isn't that what you want?